# How can I use symbols or bring back the original floor name on Tiny Tower?

Tags: tiny-tower

I recently got a "Ship & Print" in my tower. I accidentally erased the name of the floor and I want the original name back, except I am not allowed to use the "&" sign. Is there any way I can bring back the original name or use the "&" sign?

Comment: I never did find a solution. I ended up just calling it "Ship N Print". What platform is this for?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge of the game and actual testing, there is no way to bring the **&** sign back.